# Cant add title to Custom UIButton?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa, uibutton

hey Guys i've got a weird problem. If i create a custom button inside the storyboard editor and want to add a title to it, it appears right to the Button, but it should be placed centered  on top of the button. I checked all the preferences and cant find out why it doesnt work. Any ideas why it behaves like this ?

Comment: append screenshot to the topic

Comment: [click here for screenshot](http://img845.imageshack.us/img845/8521/bildschirmfoto20121118u.png)

Comment: I found the error. I set the image value not the background value. Stupid error. Sorry for wasting your time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked for me using Xcode 4.5, take a look at the screenshot:

[image]

You should check out the Alignment properties under Control (shown at the bottom right hand corner). If you select the center option for both Horizontal and Vertical you should have the same result as the image shows.